# Is curlftpfs missing in debian 12?

Tags: debian, apt, curl, ftp, fuse

Tried to install curlftpfs in debian 12 says that the package is missing.

While I understand that the package is still not active developed I use often curlftpfs inside some virtual machines transfer to transfer between various fs eg. windows/linux VMs that pass files through filezilla server and so on.

So to me would be still useful use it even in a non secure FTPS fashion of the protocol.

Is there a way to install that package o a replacing package like that without break my debian 12 installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curlftpfs` ships a single, simple binary package; you can safely install the Debian 11 version in Debian 12. Assuming you’re using `amd64`:

```
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/curlftpfs/curlftpfs_0.9.2-9+b1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./curlftpfs_0.9.2-9+b1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Copy it to /tmp/ and install from there, else you get `N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/[myuser]/curlftpfs_0.9.2-9+b1_arm64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)`  Thanks for a great shortcut!

Comment: @JimB you’re welcome, I’m glad it helped! That message is just a notice, and since the “download” is a local file system copy there’s no security impact.

Comment: Unfortunately, curlftpfs appears to be badly broken with FIleZilla-Server due to [a bug on the curlftpfs side](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=54950&p=181448&hilit=curlftpfs#p181448). It sends a "LIST -a", FileZilla-Server interprets the "-a" as path, and you get `Input/output error` on `ls` And I don't see a fork anywhere that fixes it.

Comment: An error I found using it with filezilla server is that the files downloaded are never closed really because it goes in timeout. The file itself is fine and doing a sha256 gives the right hash however the result is the client hanging for a while.